# How to interpret the output of scipy.fftpack.fft?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 44100Hz audio, which means that there are 44100 samples per second. I would like to analyze it, so I split up the data to sub-arrays with length 1024.

For each array, I apply Fourier transformation (fft), which returns with an array of complex numbers. Those numbers should be the shift and phase values.

The length of the result is 1024, just like a chunk. But I don't know, which element of the array corresponds to which frequency. I checked the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft), but the only thing I was able to find out, was that the result is symmetric, and I can skip the first part.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft

res = fft(chunk)
```

But how is it possible to find out, that what is the frequency at a given index in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this directly by taking FFT of pure tones. Here I compare: constant function (zero frequency), frequency 1 (period = sampled interval),  frequency 2 (period = half of sampled interval), and so on:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft
arr = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 9)[:-1]
for k in range(5):
  print np.round(np.abs(fft(np.cos(k*arr))), 10)
```

Result:

```
[ 8.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.]
[ 0.  0.  4.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  4.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  8.  0.  0.  0.]
```

So, the 0th entry is constant term, the entries 1 and -1 are for frequency for which the period is the time interval we sampled; the entries 2 and -2 are for period being half of sampled time interval; 3 and -3 for period being 1/3 of sampled time interval, etc, until we reach [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).

For a sample of size 1024:

- 1 and -1 are for frequency 1/1024 of sampling rate
- 2 and -2 are for frequency 2/1024 of sampling rate
- 3 and -3 are for frequency 3/1024 of sampling rate
- ...
- 512 is for Nyquist frequency, 1/2 = 512/1024 of sampling rate