# determining and filtering out low frequent component from a real dataset

Tags: python, scipy, fft, dft

I am trying to use FFT to filter out low frequency components from a signal and retain high frequency components in a real [dataset](https://www.eia.gov/electricity/gridmonitor/dashboard/) (hourly electricity demand in California). I have tried this so far:

```
X = fft(df['demand'])
y_fft_shift = fftshift(X)
n = 20 # number of low freq components to be removed (selected randomly) 
m = len(X)/2
sig_fft_filtered_img = y_fft_shift.copy()
sig_fft_filtered_img[int(m-n):int(m+n+1)] = 0
y_ifft_shift = ifftshift(sig_fft_filtered_img)
y_ifft = ifft(y_ifft_shift)

# compare original signal vs filtered signal 
plt.figure(figsize = (25, 6))
plt.plot(df['demand'],'b') #df['hour'], 
plt.plot(abs(y_ifft.real),'r')
plt.xlabel('Datetime')
plt.ylabel('demand')
plt.title('original vs filtered signal')
plt.xticks(rotation=25) 
plt.show()
```

I am not sure whether **(a) my implementation is correct, and (b) the results obtained from inverse discrete fourier transform is the expected results. For instance, if I don't take `abs(y_ifft.real)` I get negative values.**

[image: demand original vs filtered]

I tried the following two approaches on synthetic signal before applying the **second approach** to the real dataset.

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft, fftfreq
sr = 2000 # sampling rate
ts = 1.0/sr # sampling interval
t = np.arange(0,1,ts)

#generate a signal
freq = 1. 
x = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 4.
x += np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 7.   
x += 0.5* np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

y = fft(x, axis=0) #FT of original signal
freq = fftfreq(len(x), d=1.0/len(x)) #compute freq.
# define the cut-off frequency
cut_off = 4.5

# high-pass filter by assign zeros to the 
# FFT amplitudes where the absolute 
# frequencies smaller than the cut-off 
sig_fft_filtered[np.abs(freq) < cut_off] = 0

# get the filtered signal in time domain
filtered = ifft(sig_fft_filtered)
```

I compared the output from the above with the below code with a criterion that I want to remove only lowest four frequency component:

```
y = fft(x, axis=0)
y_fft_shift = fftshift(y)
n = 4
m = len(x)/2
# y_fft_shift[m-n+1:m+n+1] = 0 
sig_fft_filtered_img = y_fft_shift.copy()
sig_fft_filtered_img[int(m-n):int(m+n+1)] = 0
y_ifft_shift = ifftshift(sig_fft_filtered_img)
y_ifft = ifft(y_ifft_shift)
```

[image]

Dataset used: [link to electricity demand dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yPNZvcSoGEP-dBDeHxDnar2FRTQd4-qN/view?usp=sharing) used above

P.S.: Many answers on SO helped me to understand the concept on image denoising using FFT as well as on synthetic data but couldn't find much on applying FFT on real dataset

Ref: [High Pass Filter for image processing in python by using scipy/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094957/high-pass-filter-for-image-processing-in-python-by-using-scipy-numpy)

[How to interpret the output of scipy.fftpack.fft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992999/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-scipy-fftpack-fft?rq=3)

[How to interpret the results of the Discrete Fourier Transform (FFT) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810666/how-to-interpret-the-results-of-the-discrete-fourier-transform-fft-in-python?rq=3)

[Understanding FFT output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319313/understanding-fft-output-in-python?rq=3)

Comment: Negative values are expected in a high-pass filtered signal. Don’t take the `abs`, that doubles the frequencies.

Comment: Thank you, Cris. Could you explain/point me to a resource to understand why negative values are expected in high pass filtered signal?

Comment: Here is my simplest explanation: the FFT decomposes into sine waves. They all oscillate around 0, except for the DC component (frequency 0). If a signal is all positive, it has a DC component, as that is the offset for all the other sines. A high-pass filter removes this DC component, moving the higher-frequency components back down to oscillate around 0.

Comment: also, followup question - since it returns negative values, is it recommended not to use high pass filter for real data? Or, in other words, how can we get meaningful reconstructed signal in time domain after high pass band filter?

Comment: You can add back the offset if you like (or not zero out the DC component in the high-pass filter). In principle there's no problem with negative values in a signal, but if you need to encode it back to a WAV file or something, then you do need to add some random DC to ensure all values are positive. You can't hear the DC component anyway, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: thank you, Cris. This is helpful. I am not using audio signal. I will try the same principle for sample demand data I have above and will ask you if I have further questions. :)

Comment: Hi Cris, I used the following so that I don't zero out the DC component - `X = rfft(df['demand'])` ; `sig_fft_filtered_img = X.copy()` ; `sig_fft_filtered_img[1:40] = 0`, `y_ifft = irfft(sig_fft_filtered_img)` . I am using real version of the FFT as suggested by Reinderien. Now, I obtain a plot closer to the original signal (similar to blue line in plot 1 in the question). Have I understood it correctly? Also, when I checked the value of X[0], it is sum of all values in the original signal. I was thinking DC component is mean of the signal.

Comment: This is the equation that the FFT implements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition —— fill in k=0 and you get the sum of input samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the complex versions of the FFT; use the real ones.

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sr = 2_000  # sampling rate
ts = 1/sr  # sampling interval
t = np.arange(0, 1, ts)

# generate a signal
freq = 1
y = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 4
y += np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 7
y += 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

fft = np.fft.rfft(y)  # FT of original signal
f = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(y), d=ts)  # compute freq.

# define the cut-off frequency
f_cutoff = 4.5
i_cutoff = round(f_cutoff/sr * len(t))

# high-pass filter by assign zeros to the
# FFT amplitudes where the absolute
# frequencies smaller than the cut-off
fft_filtered = fft.copy()
fft_filtered[:1 + i_cutoff] = 0

# get the filtered signal in time domain
y_filtered = np.fft.irfft(fft_filtered)

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

ax_t: plt.Axes
ax_f: plt.Axes
fig, (ax_t, ax_f) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

ax_t.plot(t, y, label='unfiltered')
ax_t.plot(t, y_filtered, label='filtered')
ax_t.set_xlabel('t (s)')
ax_t.set_ylabel('y')
ax_t.legend()

ax_f.loglog(f, np.abs(fft), label='unfiltered')
ax_f.loglog(f, np.abs(fft_filtered), label='filtered')
ax_f.set_xlabel('f (Hz)')
ax_f.set_ylabel('|y|')
ax_f.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: plots]

Comment: @Reinderin: Hi Reinderin, if I want to do the second version i.e., instead of providing frequency threshold for filtering, I want to filter out say, k low frequency components then I guess I wouldn't be able use `ifftshift` with real version of function.

Comment: For a real-life application like utility usage, it doesn't seem useful to filter out _k_ components. The number of components will be difficult to count and might vary over time. What do you actually care about - usage over the day?

Comment: When you say "components", are you assuming that there will be one component per FFT bucket?

Comment: My actual use case is I want to know periods of frequent activity - thats why I was trying to remove the low frequency component. The data ranges for around 3 months time period, has hourly activity, say, number of tweets per hour. I filled non-activity period as zero. Since I can't provide actual data over here, I used a toy example of electricity demand data.

Comment: yeah, I am assuming one component per FFT bucket - also, I am not sure whether that is a correct assumption to make too.

Comment: It isn't. That's less useful than deliberately choosing a cutoff frequency.

Comment: Why is choosing a cutoff frequency not correct? It’s the most common thing to do! By the way, I’ve always called your “FFT buckets” the (frequency) components.

Comment: No, I didn't mean choosing a cutoff frequency is not correct; I was under the understanding that `freq` function in python requires a sampling rate. But, I guess I can use the default value of 1 (if the sampling rate is unknown?) and visualize the frequency plot and determine the frequency cutoff.

Comment: Your results cannot be meaningful unless the sampling rate is known. In this case, your power data clearly have a sampling period of one hour.

Comment: thank you, Reinderien, that makes sense. Also, what is the rationale behind using log-log plot?

Comment: For realistic data it's usually more informative when plotting spectra.